# работа bash-скрипта отличается при запуске из строки и из файла

Tags: bash

при написании скрипта непосредственно в bash всё исполняется "лучше",в чем при вызове того же кода из файла, в чём может быть причина?

```
> pid=(`pgrep konsole -u $USER | tr '\n' ' '`)
> for i in ${pid}; do SESSIONS=(`qdbus org.kde.konsole-$i | grep /Sessions/ | tr '\n' ' ' `); echo "i: "$i" Session #"$SESSIONS"\n" ; done
```

тут видно что существуют 2 процесс и в каждом запущено несколько вкладок

```
i: 906 Session #/Sessions/2
 i: 906 Session #/Sessions/3
 i: 906 Session #/Sessions/5
 i: 906 Session #/Sessions/6
 i: 906 Session #/Sessions/8
 i: 906 Session #/Sessions/9

i: 917 Session #/Sessions/1
 i: 917 Session #/Sessions/2
 i: 917 Session #/Sessions/3
 i: 917 Session #/Sessions/4
```

идентичный код записан в файл

```
#watcher.sh
pid=(`pgrep konsole -u $USER | tr '\n' ' ' `)
if [[ ${pid} ]] ; then
  for i in ${pid} ; do 
    SESSIONS=(`qdbus org.kde.konsole-$i | grep /Sessions/ | tr '\n' ' ' `)
    echo "pid: "$i" Session #"$SESSIONS"\n" 
    done
fi
```

вызываю

```
> ./watcher.sh
```

получаю:

```
pid: 906 Session #/Sessions/2\n
```

то есть из скрипта мало того, что `echo` не узнаёт `\n` и выводит как строку,
так ещё и массивы содержат только одно значение

система: manjaro, kde plasma, konsole, zsh

Зачем мне всё это?
Хотел запоминать сессию в каждом окне терминала, нашел соответствующий [скрипт](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593779/341039), но тот отказался со мной работать...

Comment: На 80% уверен что в консоли у вас bash, а скрипт запускается dash-ем. Собственно в скрипте по ссылке в первой строке есть шебанг, а у вас нет.

Comment: изначально оригинальный скрипт не сработал, я  начал дополнять его, тестируя свои отрывки кода в терминале, и в данном вопросе я привел просто **минимальный кусок**, который работает из файла неожиданным образом, хоть есть там остальная часть кода хоть нету и первая строчка совсем влияния не оказывает(проверил)

Comment: `echo` узнает `\n` с ключем `-e` вот так: `echo -e '1\n2'` и можно заменить `echo` на `printf`

Comment: @ivan, не знал, спасибо. Вообще странно, что некоторые утилиты в скрипте работают не так как в строке...

Comment: Пожалуйста, не странно если учитавать коментарий Алексея. В консоли один интерпритатор в скрипте другой отсюда и разный результат.

Answer (score 0):

Эврика, друзья

я обнаружил что конструкция вызова утилит `` var=(` ... `) ``
при вызове из скрипта, по не явной причине возвращает, только один `pid`
в то же время, конструкция  `var=$(...)`
работает одинаково при любом вызове

итоговый код моего отрывка выглядит следующим образом:

```
pid=$(pgrep konsole -u $USER  | tr '\n' ' ' )
echo -e $pid"\n"
  for i in ${pid} ; do 
    SESSIONS=$(qdbus org.kde.konsole-$i | grep /Sessions/ | tr '\n' ' ' )
    echo -e  "pid: "$i" Session #"$SESSIONS"\n" 
  done
```

ответ данного скрипта

```
906 917 

pid: 906 Session #/Sessions/10 /Sessions/2 /Sessions/3 /Sessions/5 /Sessions/6 /Sessions/8 /Sessions/9 

pid: 917 Session #/Sessions/1 /Sessions/2 /Sessions/3 /Sessions/4
```

наличие  `#!/bin/bash` в первой строке никак не влияет на исполнение скрипта

Comment: В первом случае объявляется массив, что бы вывести все данные нужно развернуть весь массив `${pid[@]}`, во втором случае значения записываются в переменную

Comment: `` считаются устаревшими и не рокомендуются к использованию. Лучше использовать `$()`.